# Is there any difference between executable binary files between distributions?

Tags: linux, kernel

As all Linux distributions use the same kernel, is there any difference between their executable binary files?

If yes, what are the main differences? Or does that mean we can build a universal linux executable file?

Comment: "Something about linux binary files" - how about spending a couple more seconds improving this question summary?

Comment: You can always edit somebody else's title/question - although please do so carefully!

Comment: do you mean universal accross the linux distributions or accross the various architectures...?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All Linux distributions use the same binary format ELF, but there is still some differences:

1. different cpu arch use different instruction set.
2. the same cpu arch may use different ABI, ABI defines how to use the register file, how to call/return a routine. Different ABI can not work together.
3. Even on same arch, same ABI, this still does not mean we can copy one binary file in a distribution to another. Since most binary files are not statically linked, so they depends on the libraries under the distribution, which means different distribution may use different versions or different compilation configuration of libraries.

So if you want your program to run on all distribution, you may have to statically link a version that depends on the kernel's syscall only, even this you can only run a specified arch.

If you really want to run a program on any arch, then you have to compile binaries for all arches, and use a shell script to start up the right one.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you! It makes more clear about the question

Answer (score 15):

All Linux ports (that is, the Linux kernel on different processors) use [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) as the file format for executables and libraries.  A specific ELF binary is labeled with a single architecture/OS on which it can run (although some OSes have compatibility to run ELF binaries from other OSes).

Most ports have support for the older [a.out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out_%28file_format%29) format.  (Some processors are new enough that there have never existed any a.out executables for them.)

Some ports support other executable file formats as well; for example, the PA-RISC port has support for HP-UX's old [SOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Object_Model_%28file_format%29) executables, and the μcLinux (nonmmu) ports support their own FLAT format.

Linux also has [`binfmt_misc`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt), which allows userspace to register handlers for arbitrary binary formats.  Some distributions take advantage of this to be able to execute Windows, .NET, or Java applications -- it's really still launching an interpreter, but it's completely transparent to the user.

---

Linux on Alpha has support for loading Intel binaries, which are run via the `em86` emulator.

It's possible to register `binfmt_misc` for executables of other architectures, to be run with [qemu-user](http://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation).

In theory, one could create a new format -- perhaps register a new "architecture" in ELF -- for fat binaries.  Then the kernel `binfmt` loader would have to be taught about this new format, and you wouldn't want to miss the `ld-linux.so` dynamic linker and the whole build toolchain.  There's been little interest in such a feature, and as far as I know, nobody is working on anything like it.

Comment: Is there a way to list all executable formats at runtime, e.g. `cat /proc/binfmt`? I could only list the `binfmt_misc` ones with `ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc`. The best I have now is `ls fs/binfmt*` on the source tree.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all linux program files use the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) standard.

Comment: Can we somehow change the ELF of the binary?

Answer (score 1):

Old Unixes also used [COFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) format. You may still find executables from times of yore in this format. Linux still has support for it (I don't know if it's compiled in current distros, though).

Comment: Linux skipped directly from a.out to ELF.  A few ports can build the *kernel* image into ECOFF format (MIPS, PowerPC) for compatibility with certain bootloaders, and Alpha may have COFF loading support for compatibility with non-native executables, but I can't find any further traces of it in the modern Linux kernel's sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a program that runs an all Linux distributions, you can consider using **scripting languages** (like `Python` and `Perl`) or a **platform independent programming language** like `Java`.

Programs written in scripting languages are complied at execution time, which means they are always compiled to match the platform they are executed on, and, hence, should always work (given that the libraries are set up properly).

Programs written in `Java`, on the other hand, are compiled before distributing them, but can be executed on any Linux distribution as long as it has a Java VM installed.

Furthermore, programs written in `Java` can be run on other operating systems like `MS Windows` and `Mac OS`.

The same is true for many programs written in `Python` and `Perl`; however, whether a `Python` or `Perl` program will work on another operating system depends on what libraries are used by that program and whether these libraries are available on the other operating systems.